# Convert 170 Digit Binary String Into Shorter Format and Back Again (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, binary, type-conversion, url-parameters

I've made a little puzzle simulation [here](http://jdgmiles.github.io/Robot%20Uprising/StackOverflowQuestionVersion.html).

The on/off states of 170 cells (some invisible to the user) are stored in an array, and to be able to recreate a particular configuration, I show the contents of the array at the bottom of the page and then that can be put in as a URL parameter to "set up" a particular configuration when the page loads [like so.](http://jdgmiles.github.io/Robot%20Uprising/StackOverflowQuestionVersion.html?00000000000000010101110100001010100010000111011101000010101000100001010111011100000000000000010001110010001000101001000100010100100010001010000001110111001000000000000000)

My problem is that the output of the array is a 170-digit binary number and this is rather cumbersome!

I tried using

```
parseInt(input,2).toString(30)
```

and

```
parseInt(input,30).toString(2)
```

As a way to simply convert this 170-digit binary number to a slimmer alphanumeric format (and back again to be read by my "set up" initialiser) but from what I can tell, the number I'm dealing with is too big to be appropriate for that kind of function.

My next thought is that I could split the 170-digit number into sections which would be digestible by the function, but that seems a little too much like reinventing the wheel when I'm sure this kind of conversion must be very common and someone would be able to set me straight about the "right" way to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to break it down into smaller components. This is because `1111...1111` = 1.4965776766268446e+51 which is greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct except that JavaScript cannot accurately represent numbers that big. Your 170 bit number loses its accuracy when you convert it to JavaScript number using `parseInt`; it does not represent the original number bit by bit.

The solution is simple: roll you own number parsing function that processes the 170 bit number in smaller chunks.

```
function encode(a) {
    var b = "";
    while (a.length > 0) {
        b = parseInt(a.slice(-5), 2).toString(32) + b;
        a = a.slice(0, -5);
    }
    return b;
}

function decode(a) {
    var b = "";
    while (a.length > 0) {
        b = ("00000" + parseInt(a.slice(-1), 32).toString(2)).slice(-5) + b;
        a = a.slice(0, -1);
    }
    return b;
}

var s = "00000000000000010101110100001010100010000111011101000010101000100001010111011100000000000000010001110010001000101001000100010100100010001010000001110111001000000000000000";
var e = encode(s); // "000lq2k8et1a45es002748kh2i4a0tp000"
var d = decode(e); // d === s
```

More general function:

```
function convert(string, base1, base2) {
    var result = "",
        chunkw = 0,  // number of characters to write per chunk
        chunkr = 0,  // number of characters to read per chunk
        padstr = "", // string of zeros for padding the write chunks
        slice;
    while (Math.pow(2, chunkw) < base1) chunkw += 1;
    while (Math.pow(2, chunkr) < base2) chunkr += 1;
    while (padstr.length < chunkw) padstr += "0";
    while (string.length > 0) {
        slice = string.slice(-chunkr);
        slice = parseInt(slice, base1).toString(base2);
        slice = (padstr + slice).slice(-chunkw);
        result = slice + result;
        string = string.slice(0, -chunkr);
    }
    return result;
}
var x = "00000000000000010101110100001010100010000111011101000010101000100001010111011100000000000000010001110010001000101001000100010100100010001010000001110111001000000000000000";
var a = convert(x, 2, 32);
var b = convert(a, 32, 2);
console.log(x + "\n" + a + "\n" + b);
//       00000000000000010101110100001010100010000111011101000010101000100001010111011100000000000000010001110010001000101001000100010100100010001010000001110111001000000000000000
//       000lq2k8et1a45es002748kh2i4a0tp000
//       00000000000000010101110100001010100010000111011101000010101000100001010111011100000000000000010001110010001000101001000100010100100010001010000001110111001000000000000000
```

Comment: [Works like a charm!](http://jdgmiles.github.io/Robot%20Uprising%20with%20Mapcodes/?000g01002004008000g04010080200g000) Thank you very much!